# Can the stack operation cause a data abort exception?

Tags: exception, assembly, arm, embedded, cpu-architecture

I know that illegal operation (such as write on an read-only area) on the memory would cause a data abort exception on ARM CPU. But I wander whether operations on the stack memory cause a data abort exception.

For example, I set the `sp` register points to a read-only memory, and I use a `push` instruction to store some value on the stack. Would the `push` operation cause a data abort exception?

Comment: Yes, you would.  Addressing modes using `sp` as the base register aren't special, and behave exactly the same as any others, unless there's some special ARM weirdness I don't know about.  The CPU doesn't really know about "stack memory" vs. any other kind of memory, the ISA just provides some short encodings (in Thumb2 mode) for ldmia / stmdb with `sp` as the pointer.

Comment: @petercorde Thanks for you explanation.

Comment: the abort isnt necessarily from the instruction, it is a from one of the busses, and the stack reads/writes are simply memory reads/writes against internal and external (to the core) busses, which have fault/abort signals, so sure you could have a fault on either a write or read transaction.

Comment: the stack really isnt special in arm, other than banking, its just another register you could use some other register than r13 in your ldm/stm (pop/push) calls...and that is all they are ldm/stm instructions which you can use for things other than stack operations.